# function that repeats indefinitely

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The code below is from the last/bottom example of Mike Bostock's D3.js path tutorial http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/. It creates a live graph of a user's page scrolling activity. If you watch the code run, you'll notice that the graph is running continuously, with the line graph sliding from right to left whether or not there's been any scrolling activity. Question: What is it about the `tick` function below that makes it run continuously, and how could it be altered to stop and start upon a click event?

```
(function() {

var n = 243,
    duration = 750,
    now = new Date(Date.now() - duration),
    count = 0,
    data = d3.range(n).map(function() { return 0; });

var margin = {top: 6, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.right,
    height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var axis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

var path = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line");

var transition = d3.select({}).transition()
    .duration(750)
    .ease("linear");

d3.select(window)
    .on("scroll", function() { ++count; });

(function tick() {
  transition = transition.each(function() {

    // update the domains
    now = new Date();
    x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data)]);

    // push the accumulated count onto the back, and reset the count
    data.push(Math.min(30, count));
    count = 0;

    // redraw the line
    svg.select(".line")
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("transform", null);

    // slide the x-axis left
    axis.call(x.axis);

    // slide the line left
    path.transition()
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")");

    // pop the old data point off the front
    data.shift();

  }).transition().each("start", tick);
})();

})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, you are missing the part where transition is defined.
Its a var of some sort but is not defined in your snippet.
That is kinda important but its not needed to know why the function continues to run.

You need to first understand both forms of the jquery each function.
http://api.jquery.com/each/ 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

transition = transition.each(function() { ... }).transition().each("start", tick);

::note that ... is hiding a lot of code::

this is essentially one line of code.

it is saying for each child of the transition var, if any, run the "..." code for it.  That is the first jquery each statement.  Inside this function $(this) would equal the child obj of transition.  The child object is never used however.

After all iterations are complete, then the transition() function is ran.  (again not sure what that is)

Lastly, each is called again but with a different form.  This time it is saying run the tick function with the string "start" as the obj.   It means that inside that function $(this) = "start".  Again the obj is never used.

Because the invoking object is never used, essentially .each is just calling the tick function.

Really, this is a very odd way of doing this.  not sure why there is such heavy use of .each.  My understanding is that .each is actually kind of slow compared to other means of iterating and invoking callbacks.

UPDATE--

to start/stop with a click I would introduce a var at the top of the script.

```
var running = true;
```

(set to false to start as not running)

then surround contents of the tick function with an if statement.

```
if(running) 
{
  transition = transition.each(function() { ... }).transition().each("start", tick);
}
```

then create one or two click handlers.  (for one toggle or start and stop buttons)

There are many ways to accomplish this.

```
$(#[button ID]).click( function(){
   if(running)
   {
     running = false;
   }
   else
   {
     running = true;
     tick();
   }

});
```

This is a basic plan of attack.  There maybe an issue when clicking the button in rapid succession.  That is for you to fix as needed.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think the OP is missing any code as you suggested (i.e. it's not missing the part where transition is defined) unless you're talking about the D3 library itself. I copied and pasted the OP code and ran it on my local machine (with D3.js included). You also didn't explain how to stop and start the tick function.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, but your update doesn't address the problem. Notice the tick function in the OP closes over some variables that it needs to keep a reference to. Your function doesn't do that. Also, your answer doesn't show how to turn off the tick function once started,

Comment: If you read my post the "some variables" are irrelevant to why the function continues to run.  It runs because it calls itself using .each.  I also clearly laid out how to to modify your code to start/stop it from running on button click.

Comment: ok, thanks, but I can't accept the answer. For the purposes of SO, the question should be answered without changing the operation of the function. None of the other code works with your solution.

Comment: hmn. How does the answer change the operation of the function?   It simply introduces an on/off flag that is changed by a click event. (what you asked for) What breaks by adding a running flag? When flipping that switch the function is allowed to complete prior to being turned off.  I think you are over complicating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem before...the transition is defined as:

```
var transition = d3.select({}).transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .ease("linear");
```

You need to run a function that changed the transition to zero:

```
transition = transition.transition(0).duration(0);
```

This essentially stops the transition from running completely.

Then to restart the transition:

```
  transition = d3.select({}).transition()
      .duration(shiftDuration)
      .ease("linear");

  tick();
```